# Under what situation will .htaccess not work for Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

vi .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|audio|editor|upload|images|js|css|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

When I try to browse http://wolaitiao.cn/install,it reports 404,so it's not working correctly.

Is it because it's a VirtualHost?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check apache error log

Answer (score 0):

first make sure Rewrite is enabled for Apache and .htaccess files are honored for the rules.

then you can simply redirect anything that does not physically exist to index:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```